# Dealing with priority encoder when output is described by 3 seperate signals

Tags: verilog

I dont know how to deal with the third part of the `priority encoder` where if more than one `1` appear in the `inputs` the output will be the `number` of the `most significant` `1`. At first i thought maybe making the `for loop` so the `i decreases` but i couldnt really apply it. And i am pretty sure there is an easier way than creating all the `4 bit` combinations for the `VD`.

The truth table:
http://prntscr.com/limnd8
and examples of how it should work :

D3=0, D2=0, D1=0, D0=0 -->  Υ1=0, Υ0=0, Zeros =1

D3=1, D2=1, D1=0, D0=1 -->  Υ1=1, Υ0=1, Zeros =0

D3=0, D2=1, D1=0, D0=1 -->  Υ1=1, Υ0=0, Zeros =0

```
module priorityenc_behav( D0, D1, D2, D3, Y0, Y1, Z);

input D0, D1, D2, D3;
output reg Y0, Y1, Z;
reg [3:0] VD;
integer i;


always @ (D0,D1,D2,D3)
 begin
    VD = 4'b0000;
    if ({D3,D2,D1,D0} == 4'b0000)
        {Y1,Y0,Z} = 3'b001;

    VD = 4'b1111;
    for (i=3; i>=0; i=i-1)
     begin
        if ((2**i) == {D3,D2,D1,D0})
         begin
            {Y1,Y0} = i;
            Z = 0;
         end
//////////////////////////
        else if(VD[ == {D3,D2,D1,D0})
         begin
            {Y1,Y0} = i;            
            Z = 0;
//////////////////////
         end
     end


 end
endmodule
```

I modified it very little bit but i cant control the else if statement correctly

```
module priorityenc_behav( D0, D1, D2, D3, Y0, Y1, Z);

input D0, D1, D2, D3;
output reg Y0, Y1, Z;
//reg [3:0] VD;
integer i;


always @ (D0,D1,D2,D3)
 begin

    if ({D3,D2,D1,D0} == 4'b0000)
        {Y1,Y0,Z} = 3'b001;

    for (i=3; i>=0; i=i-1)
     begin
        if ({D3,D2,D1,D0} == (2**i))
         begin
            {Y1,Y0} = i;
            Z = 0;
         end
        else if({D3,D2,D1,D0}>2**i)
             begin
                {Y1,Y0} = i;            
                Z = 0;
             end    
     end


 end
endmodule
```

Ok, I reverted my `for` back so `i` increases and it works i think . I will leave it a little more if someone want to see anything or he/she can make the code make less space but leaving the signals as they are(or if they add one reg like the commented one kinda)

Comment: start with using the bitwise`or` instead of the comparison: `if ( ( (2**i) | {D3,D2,D1,D0})) != 0)`.  This will ignore other '1'.

Comment: but thats the purpose of writing that(mine). to ignore other ~1~ and only those with 1 ~1~ will make the statement true. Your statement has no logical meaning (maybe)

Comment: prevent* not ignore

Comment: then explain it better. You said that you need the first (most significant) '1'. I did not say that your program will work as is, but this would help you to figure out the rest. If this is too complicated, try to use `casez` instead.

Comment: i explained ,added truth table and examples and also noted the part of the code that needs correction and completion. i dont think much more can be explained. but appreciate it.  and y using case will help but i need to find that particular solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a variant based on your code which works. The idea is that you check using the first '1' in the Ds and stop checking after it. To check them you can use bitwise `&`.

```
module priorityenc_behav( D0, D1, D2, D3, Y0, Y1, Z);
   input D0, D1, D2, D3;
   output reg Y0, Y1, Z;

   integer    i;
   reg        flag;


  always @* begin
   if ({D3,D2,D1,D0} == 4'b0000)
    {Y1,Y0,Z} = 3'b001;
   else begin
     flag = 0;
     for (i=3; i>=0; i=i-1) begin
      if (flag == 0 && ({D3,D2,D1,D0} & (4'b0001 << i)) != 0) begin
       flag = 1;
       {Y1, Y0} = i;
       Z = 1'b0;
      end
     end
    end
   end

endmodule
```

The other version is much simpler and more readable in your case:

```
module priorityenc_behav( D0, D1, D2, D3, Y0, Y1, Z);

input D0, D1, D2, D3;
output reg Y0, Y1, Z;

always @* begin
 casez({D3,D2,D1,D0})
  4'b0000: {Y1,Y0,Z} = 3'b001; 
  4'b0001: {Y1,Y0,Z} = 3'b000;
  4'b001?: {Y1,Y0,Z} = 3'b010;
  4'b01??: {Y1,Y0,Z} = 3'b100;
  4'b1???: {Y1,Y0,Z} = 3'b110;
 endcase
end
endmodule
```